# Как настроить вывод лимитирования?

Tags: pdo, php, limit, mysql

Есть табличка с комментариями к постам, со следующими столбцами:

author, text, post_id, datetime, id.

ID - автоинкрементный индекс поста в таблице.

Так вот, пытаюсь прикрепить к этому всему лимитирование вывода комментариев следующим образом:

```
   // тут кривовато высчитываем лимит.
    if ($page == 0){
        $page = 1;
        $linit = "0, 20";
        }else{
        $start = $page * 20;
        $end = $start+20;
        $limit = "$start, $end";
        }
    // собственно, запрашиваю

     $prepare = $db->prepare("SELECT * from `posts` where `id` = :id LIMIT $limit ");
    $prepare -> bindParam(":id", $topic, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepare -> execute();
    if ($prepare ->rowCount == 0){
    echo '<p class = "error">',$nopost,'</p>';
    }else{
    while($pre = $prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    // ну тут уже понятно, что
    }
    }
```

Так вот, при таком подходе посты не получает ВООБЩЕ.

Вот и вопрос такой: как можно это дело исправить-то, чтоб лимитированно выводилось?

Comment: А на какой странице ($page) ошибки выводит?

    $linit = "0, 20";

Если на нулевой, то может быть все-таки $limit?

И чему равен $topic? Может быть, такой записи нет?

Comment: > $linit

вместо $limit.

Comment: @BOPOH, переменная $topic  - идентефикатор поста. $page - страницы комментариев. 

В общем, попробовал набить побольше комментариев - стало выводить, НО, выводит не все, а только 3 последних. 

Если страница нулевая, то лимит 0,20 же.

Comment: @Etki, исправил - всё равно выкидывает то же, что я описал в комментарии выше.
Хотя нет, выкидывает почему то с определенного коммента, на попытку смены страницы не реагирует никак.

Comment: 1. Выведите значение $topic, потом подставьте его в sql и выполните ваш запрос в mysql - увидите, что должна выводить страница.
2. Исправьте $linit на $limit.

И, кстати, limit можно и без условий подсчитать:

    $page = intval($page);
    $start = $page * 20;
    $end = $start + 20;
    $limit = "$start, $end";

Будет аналогично вашему условию.

UPD: а как вы пытаетесь страницу сменить? Говорю же - выведите номер страницы, вставьте его в sql и попробуйте выполнить запрос напрямую в mysql, может быть, увидите, что не так.

Comment: @BOPOH, счетчик страниц у меня там расчитывается и выводит ссылки типа post123?page=1

Comment: 1. Чему равно $topic?
2. Чему равно $page?

Не надо писать, что там должно находиться, пишите только то, что там действительно есть. Вдруг в этом проблема? Если бы проблем не было - не было бы вашего вопроса.

Говорю же - выведите то, что должен вывести ваш скрипт - на 80 процентов сразу же найдете проблему.

К тому же $topic - это post123? Почему тогда PDO::PARAM_INT? Попробуйте вообще его убрать.

Comment: Там и есть то, что должно быть.

Конкретнее, и коротко:

$topic = $_GET['post'];

А ЧПУ преобразует ссылку вида script.php?post=123 в post123

Проверил - и в $topic хранится то, что надо, и в $page. 

Дайте минутку, скину побольше кода.

Comment: И еще, может, пальцем в небо, но все же...

>> author, text, post_id, datetime, id

id - это id комментария? Т.е. если вы хотите выбрать комментарии определенного поста, то надо выбирать по post_id? Тогда почему вы выбираете по id?

Единственное - непонятно почему выводит тогда 3 последних. Вы сами, что ли, в базу добавили с одинаковым id?

И еще раз - выведите то, что в $topic, в $page и $limit, вставьте в запрос и выполните его ручками в mysql. Если то, что выведет клиент, не совпадает с тем, что на странице, значит, надо смотреть, что творится в генераторе страницы, а не в выборке.